# How to calculate FID for a set with a small number of images?

Tags: model-evaluation, metric, generative-models, gan

I need to evaluate my generative model using FID (Fréchet inception distance). However, the dataset of real images that I have only contains 2719 examples. I've read that the authors of the metric recommend using a minimum sample size of 10,000 to calculate the FID, otherwise the true FID of the generator will be underestimated.

How then should I calculate this metric on my dataset? There is not much information on the internet on how to deal with such a problem. The only thing I found was this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.07023) and its [implementation](https://github.com/mchong6/FID_IS_infinity).